# how to get contacts´ device id?

Tags: android, firebase, android-contacts

I want to get something unique from the users contact list, to check if some of his contacts are signed in to my app (with Firebase), how can I do that?

This doesn't work that well:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                        String number = tm.getLine1Number();
```

because it doesn't work with all devices.

Answer (score 0):

If your users are logging into your app using their phone number (like in Whatsapp, Telegram, [Digits](https://get.digits.com/)) then you can check the user's contacts' phone numbers to see which contact has logged in to your app and who isn't,

If your users are logging into your app using their email-address (e.g. using [Google account sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)) then you check the user's contacts' email-addresses to check that.

P.S you need to have the `Contacts` permission on Android M+ devices to be able to read from the Contacts DB.

Comment: normally what an app would do is get all the email addresses from all contacts, hash them to avoid any privacy concerns, and send them to the server so it'll check which ones are already signed in and which aren't